# error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts

Tags: angular

I' working with an angular project. I thought that everything is ok. but there has an error like follow. It is a trouble for me that how It happen. If any one know about it I highly appreciate your support

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/card/typings/card module.d.ts(12,55): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.node_modules/@angular/material/card/typings/cardmodule.d.ts(20,55):error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
```

Then what should i\I do

Comment: Can you try reinstalling angular material? `npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations`

Comment: How are you importing `CardModule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to delete your node_module folder from the project and re-install again using **npm install** 
it'll will work for you